# API rest call for Atlassian

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently building a jql issue search via the rest api of Atlassian.
Here is my code, or better the code provided by Atlassian:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

fetch('https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=jqlsearch', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(
      'username', 'apikey'
    ).toString('base64')}`,
    Accept: 'application/json'
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(
      `Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`
    )
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

I now receive the errormessage "Error at Script :1:77". And to be honest, I'm struggling with troubleshooting that, I don't know what that error message is standing for.

My first guess was that there is an error in line 1 at the 77th character but there is no 77th character in line 1.

Excited to hear what's wrong here. (probably it's a layer 8 problem :-) )
And forgive me my probably basic question but I couldn't find an answer in my google search.

I tried to change the fetch message with a different jql search and tried another domain.
But I think it's more a problem somewhere in the code than a connectionerror.

PS: Here is the documentation provided by Atlassian: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-search/#api-rest-api-3-search-get

The fetch error is too long, so I post it in a single comment:

FetchError: request to https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=jqlsearch failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mydomain.atlassian.net at ClientRequest. (/usr/share/nodejs/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1697:14) at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20) at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:427:9) at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20) at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8) at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) { type: 'system', errno: 'EAI_AGAIN', code: 'EAI_AGAIN' }

I'm trying to run the script at StackBlitz as a Test, is that the reason for the fetch error?

Best Regards
Niklas